# Apache2 / tomcat / MySQL / PageSpeed Server hanging once a day

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, java, mysql5.5

My server started to hang at least once a day. It remains so until I restart Tomcat. I'm not sure yet which part causes the problem, so I'm trying to work on several hypotheses:

- My website is served through Google's PageSpeed, so I doubt I'm under a DDoS attack.
- When it hangs, I have to restart both apache2 and tomcat. So I can't tell which one is causing the problem.
- When the server hangs, I check mysql's processlist, and I find a dozen of idle connections. This means that the database is not overloaded.
- When the server hangs, I see few errors like this one. So it it could be the case that the problem resides within the connection between my Java code and MySQL:

  ```
  java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
      at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:870)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:734)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:778)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getObject(ResultSetImpl.java:4419)
      at com.mypackage.SqlUtils.getResultMapList(SqlUtils.java:66)
  ```

My centralized code for retrieving results from the database is:

```
public List<ResultMap> getResultMapList(String sql) {
    List<ResultMap> rows = new LinkedList<>();
    try (Connection conn = getConnection();
            ResultSet res = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(sql)) {
        while (res.next()) {
            ResultMap row = new ResultMap();
            ResultSetMetaData meta = res.getMetaData();
            for (int i = 1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                row.put(meta.getColumnLabel(i).toLowerCase(), res.getObject(i)); // Line 66
            }
            rows.add(row);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rows;
}
```

My connection is pooled:

```
public Connection getConnection() {
    if (datasource == null) {
        PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
        p.setUrl(myURL);
        p.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        p.setUsername(dbprefix + "user1");
        p.setPassword(password);
        p.setJmxEnabled(true);
        p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
        p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
        p.setTestOnReturn(false);
        p.setValidationInterval(30000);
        p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(1000);
        p.setMaxActive(20);
        p.setMaxIdle(5);
        p.setInitialSize(5);
        p.setMaxWait(10000);
        p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(30);
        p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(10000);
        p.setMinIdle(2);
        p.setLogAbandoned(true);
        p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
        p.setFairQueue(true);
        p.setJdbcInterceptors("org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;"
                + "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");
        datasource = new DataSource();
        datasource.setPoolProperties(p);
    }
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = datasource.getConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
}
```

`ResultMap` extends `LinkedHashMap<String, Object>`, and I'm using it only to store the fields retrieved in the `ResultSet`.

Software installed: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu), Mysql: 5.5.40 (InnoDB), Tomcat: 8.0.15, Java: 1.8.0_25.

Any suggestions about why the server is hanging?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is logrotate, which is restarting mysql and then your connection to the db needs to be closed + reopened?

Comment: Why would logrotate restart mysql?

Comment: in order to close and reopen the logs. well actually this should not require a restart, but still maybe?